# Running a program using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to run a program using a tensoflow installed on a virtual machine but it gives me the following errors and I couldn't be able to get solution from Google :) Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Here is the error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: invalid ELF header
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, Tare, could you please update your question and include also the the code that produces this error?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely installed the wrong version of tensorflow check [the download page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html) and make sure that you installed the version that matches your device.